# PASSWORD_HASHERS setting in Django

Tags: python, django

i have an error when ever i try to login by any User 
error

> Unknown password hashing algorithm 'sahar'. Did you specify it in the
>   PASSWORD_HASHERS setting?

Views.Py

```
def Login(request):
    state = "Please log in below..."
    username = password = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
                else:
                    return render_to_response('auth.html',RequestContext(request))

        else:
                return render_to_response('auth.html',RequestContext(request))
    else:
            return render_to_response('auth.html',RequestContext(request)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It means there is a plain text `'sahar'` stored as the password of the account of a user who tries to log in.
Update the password of the user in Admin or in `manage.py shell`

```
user = User.objects.get(username=username)

# use set_password method
user.set_password('sahar')
user.save()

# INSTEAD OF 
user.password = 'sahar'
user.save()
```

Also check your other views to correct the `user.password = '...'` and `User.objects.create(password='...')` usages.

Comment: Was just about to say the same thing. Seems like a bug, though, doesn't it, that it actually echoes the raw password?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, the current behavior is not good: it treats a raw password which is no longer useful for logging, as hasher and even show it back. Perhaps resetting the password and warning admin immediately is more appropriate. Also, maybe the `password` field should be tweaked not to accept direct assignment, but wraps the content automatically w/ hashers.

Comment: iam sorry as i um a new Django learner but 'sahar' is the actual password of the user iam trying to login  with and it's stated in the database that way

Comment: @MaiZuhair, the point is that you shouldn't save it in the database that way, you should do what okm says above.

Comment: @MaiZuhair you could also run `./manage.py changepassword username` to change the password for the user. But the main thing you should not ignore is to check your views and ensure there is *not* `user.password = '...'` or `User.objects.create(password='...')` usages

Comment: @DanielRoseman Nice! seems `User.objects.create()` is "prone to error"... The convention makes things a bit surprising here.

Comment: @okm: True. The implementation of `create` on the `User` manager should probably be overridden to raise an exception if `password` is passed in as a kwarg.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yep that could be fine

Answer (score 1):

**This is the best way to save log in details
you can create an object from the form
as**

```
user = form.save(commit=False)
```

**then clean the data to remove any scripts entered in the form fields.**

```
username = form.cleaned_data['username']
password = form.cleaned_data['password']
user.set_password(password)
user.save()
```