# Django: creating form which has relationship

Tags: django, forms, relationship, formset

I've prepared a model with a relationship.
I'd like to get a form which will make it possible to create User for that form.

Could someone explain me how it can be resolved?

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    website = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    accepted_rules = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    accepted_rules_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class UserProfile(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile

@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        form = UserProfile(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            website = form.cleaned_data['website']
            accepted_rules = form.cleaned_data['accepted_rules']

            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']



            form.save()


            print "All Correct"            


    return TemplateResponse(request, 'base.html', {
                             'form':form,
                             }
                            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way I would consider.  First of all, I would name the form UserProfileForm so that it's name doesn't conflict with the model.  Add extra fields to your UserProfile form for the fields required to create a new user.  Create the new User instance.  Use form.save(commit=False) so that you can add the newly created User instance to the UserProfile instance and save it.  There may be a more elegant way.

```
from django import forms

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@csrf_protect
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = User(username=username, email=email)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            user_profile = form.save(commit=False)
            user_profile.user = user
            user_profile.save()
            print "All Correct"            
return TemplateResponse(request, 'base.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Please aware that `User(username, password, email)` usage is incorrect. You need to pass the model class named arguments such as `username=username` to work: normally `pk` is the first parameter of the constructor hence you actually get a User() w/ `pk` set to username. Furthermore, refs [the post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246463/password-hashers-setting-in-django/10246947#10246947), don't use `password=...`, which has been implicitly done in your code,  for `User` construction.

Comment: @okm, absolutely, good catch.  I was mixing `User.objects.create_user()` and still had wrong argument order, and edited above to also reflect proper password setting.

Comment: Are relationships supposed to be handled in views? It seems more logical to encapsulate all of that in the form. I haven't seen much documentation on it thought...