# Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm

Tags: django

One of the users on my site recently managed to trigger this traceback while attempting to login. In Django Admin, his password reads `Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm.`

I have no idea what might have caused this. So far this has been an isolated case and I and other users have managed to successfully sign up and login to the site.

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/home/gituser/.virtualenvs/bbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
   response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

 File "/var/git/bbox/userprofile/views.py", line 67, in login_view
   if form.is_valid():

 File "/home/gituser/.virtualenvs/bbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 124, in is_valid
   return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)

 File "/home/gituser/.virtualenvs/bbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 115, in _get_errors
   self.full_clean()

 File "/home/gituser/.virtualenvs/bbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 271, in full_clean
   self._clean_form()

 File "/home/gituser/.virtualenvs/bbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 299, in _clean_form
   self.cleaned_data = self.clean()

 File "/var/git/bbox/userprofile/forms.py", line 83, in clean
   self.user_cache = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

 File "/home/gituser/.virtualenvs/bbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 45, in authenticate
   user = backend.authenticate(**credentials)

 File "/home/gituser/.virtualenvs/bbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 15, in authenticate
   if user.check_password(password):

 File "/home/gituser/.virtualenvs/bbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 304, in check_password
   return check_password(raw_password, self.password, setter)

 File "/home/gituser/.virtualenvs/bbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py", line 42, in check_password
   hasher = get_hasher(algorithm)

 File "/home/gituser/.virtualenvs/bbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py", line 115, in get_hasher
   "setting?" % algorithm)

ValueError: Unknown password hashing algorithm ''. Did you specify it in the PASSWORD_HASHERS setting?
```

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? My first guess is that the password storage string has been corrupted somehow, as it is stored in a fixed format.

Comment: possibly duplicated w/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246463/password-hashers-setting-in-django/10246947#10246947

Comment: @okm Hmm I think it might be related but the thing is, it's so far been an isolated case. Other newer users have managed to sign up and log in successfully after this guy.. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any code which incorrectly operates on password then? Or any `LogEntry` recorded for the password changing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of setting your password to an empty string, set the password as unusable using [`set_unusable_password()` method of `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_unusable_password):

```
user.set_unusable_password()
```

See more in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_unusable_password

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the user was an 'invited' user. In my invite code, I was creating the user with this block of code:

```
    user = User.objects.create(
            username=cd['email'],
            email=cd['email'],
            first_name=cd['first_name'],
            last_name=cd['last_name'],
            is_active=False)
```

As you can see, I was not setting a password. The fix is to apply a temporary password as the user will be asked to create a new password once he reaches the validation link sent to him in the email.

```
    # set a random pw. user will be prompted to change
    # on log in
    user.set_unusable_password()
    user.save()
```

So basically, you will get this traceback if you create a user object without setting a password and try to log him into your site (using django's auth system).

Comment: -1 No, because of two reasons: 1) You should use [`user.set_unusable_password()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_unusable_password) as mentioned by [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_unusable_password), 2) Setting password to `random.randint(100000, 999999)` makes it extremely easy to guess (you have chance higher than `1` to million to guess at the first time and you only need less than `899999` attempts to be sure what the password is). Do not go that way.

Comment: Cool thanks. Wasn't aware of that method. Will go that route instead.

Comment: FYI, as of at least django v1.4, `set_unusable_password()` is equivalent to setting the password hash to "!". The exclamation mark is to distinguish with "unset" passwords. This will allow you to add batches of user in a single step (password="!" in the `create` statement)