# Django invalid password format for ModelForm PasswordInput

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have seen a lot of [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534758/invalid-password-format-or-unknown-hashing-algorithm) answers and official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/) for this issue but find no solution yet.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Userform(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'joeschmoe', 'name': 'username'}))
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'joeschmoe@xyz.com', 'name': 'email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'name': 'password'}))
    repassword = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'name': 'repassword'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'repassword']
```

**View.py**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Userform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            repassword = form.cleaned_data['repassword']

            form.save()

            return render(request, 'base/index.html')
    else:
        form = Userform()
    return render(request, 'base/register.html', {'form': form})
```

This form is successfully registering but showing `Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm`. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new user you should use `user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)`. you can refer [to that](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html). Don't add the password to your `Userform`

Your form :

```
class Userform(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'joeschmoe', 'name': 'username'}))
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'joeschmoe@xyz.com', 'name': 'email'}))


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'repassword']
```

Your view :

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Userform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            repassword = form.cleaned_data['repassword']              

            if password == repassword:   
                
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

                form.save()

            return render(request, 'base/index.html')
    else:
        form = Userform()
    return render(request, 'base/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Works but don't need comparing  `password == repassword`. Without compare it's working

Comment: Ha ok, happy that it helped you.