# Error when I create new user Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I can create the new user, but when I try to login appear this error:

> Unknown password hashing algorithm. Did you specify it in the PASSWORD_HASHERS setting?

I don't know because failed. if I am using the `forms.ModelForm`

Form.py

```
class addUseF(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = {'is_staff','is_active','is_superuser','last_login','date_joined','user_permissions',}
```

View.py

```
def addUseV(request):
        form = addUseF()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = addUseF(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/superUser/')
        else:
            ctx = {'form':form}
            return  render_to_response('adm/adduser.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    ctx = {'form':form}
    return render_to_response('adm/adduser.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

plus the label of the key characters is not hiding.
Example I write the key "root" and I see "root and I should see "****"

Comment: You have to save the password using `user.set_password` else it stores as plain text rather than a hash. Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246463/password-hashers-setting-in-django

Comment: You also want to check the SQL the first chars of the password tell you the hasher used.

Comment: If I tryed it, but I am using forms.ModelForm, then I haven't a text imput ['password'], and in my template only i have {{ form.as_p }}